# Putting JSF composite components in a subfolder based hierarchy

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I'm roughly following [this](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.de/p/in-jsf-2.html) guide for creating composite components in JSF 2.2. I've managed to define and use a component, but I'm having problems properly organizing the components. In all tutorials the components are put into one directory and the files' names define the tag name.

```
META-INF/resources/ts
                   +-plainbox.xhtml
                   +-showcasebox.xhtml
```

I'd prefer having categories and a directory for each element, with bundled JS, CSS and images. I'd like to use a structure like this:

```
META-INF/resources/ts
                   +-containers
                   |  +-plainbox
                   |  |  +-plainbox.xhtml
                   |  |  +-plainbox.css
                   |  +-showcasebox
                   |     +-showcasebox.xhtml
                   |     +-showcasebox.js
                   +-otherstuff
                      +-...
```

Unfortunately, when using this structure I need to reference each component by an own namespace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ts="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ts/containers/showcasebox"
    xmlns:ts2="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ts/containers/plainbox">
<head jsf:id="head">
</head>
    <body>
        <ts:showcasebox>hello world</ts:showcasebox>
        <ts2:plainbox>foo bar</ts2:plainbox>
    </body>
</html>
```

Having to reference the categories one by one would be okay, but having a new namespace for each component is unbearable. Also I've read that this nesting is against the specification.

Is it possible to have a hierarchy of composite components in JSF with only one namespace? How are frameworks like Primefaces doing it? Are they defining all elements in Java?

Comment: _"How are frameworks like Primefaces doing it? Are they defining all elements in Java?"_ Yes they are

Comment: Sigh. looks like this is not possible. Neither using a tag library nor composite components. Only with custom components (Java). What a huge design deficit.

Comment: Howcome you think it is not possible with taglibs? Tried this https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/jsf22-cc-taglib/ ?

Comment: I did. It states in another part that the resource definition is limited to a library directory and a component file. The spec doesn't allow slashes inside library or component name. Effectively this disallows nesting components in sub-directories.

Comment: Does it disallow slashes in the resource-id to?

Comment: No, but the slash-separated fields in the resource-id are strictly defined. The namespaces I used above are somehow supported, but an implementation detail and can break on every update or JSF engine switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite component folder structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608187/composite-component-folder-structure)

Comment: isn't that post about the composite-library value and not the resource-id's?

Comment: Not sure. AFAIK the resource-id is made of the library name, the resource name and a few optional fields like version etc. I couldn't find any clean solution for nesting component resources.